# Trying to identify all records in a table that correspond with a second table, where none of the records in the second contain a specific value

Tags: ms-access

I have a table (table 1) with case information (one record for each case number) and then a second table (table 2) with a record for each claim associated with the cases in table 1. I am trying to identify the cases from table 1 that have "Open" in the "Case Status" field (in table 1) where NONE of the associated claims from table 2 have "Selected" in the "Claim Status" field (in table 2).

For example, if an "Open" case in table 1 has 5 claims in table 2, and one of those 5 claims has "Selected" in the "Claim Status" field, I don't want any of those 5 claim records included in the output. But if all of those 5 claims have something other than "Selected" in the claim status field, I want those 5 claims included in the output.

So far I am only getting claims for open cases that are not in "Selected" status, whether or not any other claims with the same case number have "Selected" as the claim status, which is not what I need. But I am not sure how to write the query to only include those records where none of the claims for a case are in "Selected" status.

I am using MS Access for Microsoft 365 MSO

Thank you!

Comment: Edit question to provide sample data and desired output as formatted text tables. Show attempted code.

Answer (score 1):

Try using IN() function.

```
SELECT table1.*, table2.* 
FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.ID = table2.ID_FK 
WHERE ID NOT IN(SELECT ID_FK FROM table2 WHERE ClaimStatus = "Selected") 
AND CaseStatus = "Open";
```

Modify SQL as appropriate for your actual table and field names.

Comment: I tried this but when I run it, it is asking me to enter a parameter value for ID_FK.

Comment: Use whatever is the actual name of field in your table. Same with table names. I don't know your db structure since you did not provide that in your question so you need to modify SQL as appropriate.